# Why does this maven JDA dependency version not work?

Tags: java, xml, dependencies, discord-jda

I am trying to make a discord bot for the first time and have run into a problem.
When I'm trying to import JDA(https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA) it underlines the version red.
When I use a slightly older version I also can't seem to import anything.

```xml
 <dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
         <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
         <version>4.2.0_204</version>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

[image: With working version]

Image is with a working version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added:

```
<repository>
    <id>jcenter</id>
    <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
</repository>
```

repository in you POM? The release version you are using is not present on Maven Central. Please refer [this guide](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/releases) with installation instruction.

Comment: I added this already yes and am now using version 4.2.0_168 , It doesn't give a red underline. What do they exactly mean with changing the url to https, which url? The one from jcenter?

Comment: yes. The https is a secure version. This is the version of the protocol that you should be using

Comment: Ok, the version works now, but I can't seem to import anything. If I type "import net" it only says "netspace" and doesn't recognize it.

Comment: I guess you are using `Idea`. Open `pom` file and press `ctrl+shift+o` to **Load Changes**. If this still doesn't work out, "Invalidate and restart" your ide from "File" menu.

Comment: Make sure your java source files are in `src/main/java`

Comment: @Minn @Prashant I tried `ctrl+shift+o` in the pom file, I invalidated and restarted without success and I am certain that it's in the right folder. I am indeed using Idea and it still doesn't want to work. I think I'll do a clean install

Comment: As a last resort, you could delete *.iml file and *.idea directory from your project root and try reimporting the project.

Comment: For some reason I don't see my final comment from yesterday, but I solved it by doing a clean install.